# React - Changing the state of an array doesn't render correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add data to an array in various indexes depending on which element the user clicks on, but the last element of the array keeps getting re-rendered.

I believe the problem initiates from the array elements being rendered in a separate component and returned to the main component that contains the state.

**[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vyx95280y) is the example code that basically encapsulates the problem.**

State (which is correct):

[image]

What actually gets rendered:

[image]

Comment: I dont understand what you try to do. You want on button click to add a new element to the array that gets rendered. But how do you want to determine where to insert the new element in the array? And how do you determine what will the new element be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Letter component, you are setting a 'letter' property on the class instance, (`this.letter`) rather than using React's built in methods for managing props and state (`this.props.letter`)

Because you're using the array index as a key in the render method of `app.js` , React will keep the existing component at that index when re-rendering the list. Because your 'letter' property hasn't changed on that component you'll get the same text.

In short, use props and state to store information.  Refrain from setting `this.{variableName}` in components unless you're storing information that isn't needed for the component (or it's children) to render.

In your case you need to change the render method of your letter component from

```
render() {
   return this.letter.text
}
```

To

```
render() {
   return this.props.letter.text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using the array index as 'key' in array.map() and then meddling with the index. This is not recommended and may cause undesired behaviours as per [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Instead declare a separate id like this

```
this.elements = [{id: 1, text: 'a'}, {id:2, text: 'b'}, {id:3, text: 'c'}]
```

And use key={element.id} inside the array.map().

This should also solve the problem.

Comment: How would I calculate the id of the new element in relation to the ids of existing data? Do I need to recalculate ids of a, b, c, once I insert d after a?

Comment: Not necessarily, it really depends on the use case. If you do not need to store this information anywhere just create some random hash for the key. The idea is to keep this key unique for react to uniquely identify the child elements.